# MakeUppercase not working with .TTF fonts

Tags: fonts, pdftex

I have a set of Sabon fonts that I would like to use for my dissertation.

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
    BoldFont={sabon-bold.ttf},
    ItalicFont={sabon-it.ttf},
    BoldItalicFont={sabon-boldit.ttf}
]{sabon-regular.ttf}
```

Everything seems to be fine but I noticed that my chapter titles are not in uppercase like I want them to be:

```
\RequirePackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\PreContentTitleFormat}{\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\scshape\Large}
{\Large\filleft\textls{\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}} \Huge\thechapter}
{1ex}
{}
[\vspace{1ex}\titlerule]}
\newcommand{\ContentTitleFormat}{\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\scshape\huge}
{\Large\filleft\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \Huge\thechapter}
{1ex}
{\titlerule\vspace{1ex}\filright}
[\vspace{1ex}\titlerule]}
\newcommand{\PostContentTitleFormat}{\PreContentTitleFormat}
\PreContentTitleFormat
```

[image]

When I remove the fonts, the chapter titles are in uppercase. What could be the cause of this problem?

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
    BoldFont={sabon-bold.TTF},
    ItalicFont={sabon-it.TTF},
    BoldItalicFont={sabon-boldit.TTF}
]{sabon-regular.TTF}

\RequirePackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\PreContentTitleFormat}{\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\scshape\Large}
{\Large\filleft\textls{\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}} \Huge\thechapter}
{1ex}
{}
[\vspace{1ex}\titlerule]}
\newcommand{\ContentTitleFormat}{\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\scshape\huge}
{\Large\filleft\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \Huge\thechapter}
{1ex}
{\titlerule\vspace{1ex}\filright}
[\vspace{1ex}\titlerule]}
\newcommand{\PostContentTitleFormat}{\PreContentTitleFormat}
\PreContentTitleFormat

\begin{document}
\ContentTitleFormat

\chapter{Introduction}
Hello
\end{document}
```

I would like to achieve something like this:

[image]

Comment: Are you using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX?

Comment: I'm not too sure because I am currently using writeLaTeX to host the files. If I'm not mistaken, writeLaTeX supports XeLaTeX ([source](https://www.writelatex.com/help/183-can-i-use-the-pstricks-package-on-writelatex)).

Comment: Also, I tried switching the engine to XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX but the problem persists.

Comment: Please, make the code snippets into a full compilable example.

Comment: By "uppercase", do you maybe mean "small caps"?

Comment: @Dennis I downloaded the project (and will dispose of the probably non free fonts as soon as possible). When compiling I get the warning `Font shape `EU1/sabon-regular.TTF(0)/m/sc' undefined, using `EU1/sabon-regular.TTF(0)/m/n' instead`. You are not asking for the title to be uppercase with the setting you have in `\titleformat`.

Comment: @egreg Please excuse my inexperience. The settings are from a template that uses `\renewcommand\rmdefault{psb}` to change the font. I gave up trying to compile the .TTF files because I wasn't getting anywhere. Anyway, I have uploaded a new picture that shows my desired output. How do I achieve this?

Comment: @Dennis You can't get that with the available TrueType fonts, which have no small caps. That picture shows a badly faked small caps font (the fake is not your fault): compare the thickness of the stems in “I” and in “N”, they are visually clashing. Rather than a fake small caps font, I'd prefer all-caps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you remove the call for the fonts the chapter titles are not uppercase, but in small caps.

The problem is your Sabon fonts have no small caps and the warning

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU2/sabon-regular.TTF(0)/m/sc' undefined
(Font)              using `EU2/sabon-regular.TTF(0)/m/n' instead
```

is issued.

If you want your titles to be uppercase, you need to have a trailing `\MakeUppercase` in the last mandatory argument to `\titleformat` like so

```
\newcommand{\ContentTitleFormat}{%
  \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\huge}% removed \scshape
    {\Large\filleft\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \Huge\thechapter}
    {1ex}
    {\titlerule\vspace{1ex}\filright\MakeUppercase}
    [\vspace{1ex}\titlerule]%
}
```

With this change I get

[image]

A better specification for your fonts would be

```
\setmainfont[
  Ligatures=TeX,% can be omitted with the latest version of fontspec
  Extension=.TTF,
  UprightFont=*-regular,
  BoldFont=*-bold,
  ItalicFont=*-it,
  BoldItalicFont=*-boldit,
]{sabon}
```

I propose some further changes: the chapter number clashes with the word “CHAPTER”, because the thickness of the number is much bigger. Some letter spacing within all-caps is recommended.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont[
      Ligatures=TeX,% can be omitted with the latest version of fontspec
      Extension=.TTF,
      UprightFont=*-regular,
      BoldFont=*-bold,
      ItalicFont=*-it,
      BoldItalicFont=*-boldit,
    ]{sabon}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\PreContentTitleFormat}{%
  \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=4}\Large}
    {}% nothing is necessary
    {1ex}
    {\MakeUppercase}
    [\vspace{1ex}\titlerule]%
}
\newcommand{\ContentTitleFormat}{%
  \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\addfontfeatures{LetterSpace=4}\huge}
  {\LARGE\filleft\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}
  {1ex}
  {\titlerule\vspace{1ex}\filright\MakeUppercase}
  [\vspace{.5ex}\titlerule]%
}
\newcommand{\PostContentTitleFormat}{\PreContentTitleFormat}
\PreContentTitleFormat

\begin{document}
\ContentTitleFormat

\chapter{Introduction}
Hello
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Dennis I proposed some other changes to fix some weaknesses in the typesetting.

Comment: Thank you so much, the changes that you made are perfect!